# ipAddress sorter issue in jQuery Tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

So I've added the jQuery(latest) tablesorter to my table and every column works perfectly except the column containing ip addresses (ipv4). It's sorting most of them but leaves out some others.

Correct me if I'm wrong but parsers are not needed in that case right? Any ideas on how to approach that problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The ipAddress parser in tablesorter is broken with respect to IP addresses which have any single digit levels (for example, the **6** in **123.45.6.78**).

Here is the stock code:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "ipAddress",
    is: function (s) {
        return /^\d{2,3}[\.]\d{2,3}[\.]\d{2,3}[\.]\d{2,3}$/.test(s);
    }, format: function (s) {
        var a = s.split("."),
            r = "",
            l = a.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var item = a[i];
            if (item.length == 2) {
                r += "0" + item;
            } else {
                r += item;
            }
        }
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(r);
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

Here is a corrected version:

```
ts.addParser({
    id: "ipAddress",
    is: function (s) {
        return /^\d{1,3}[\.]\d{1,3}[\.]\d{1,3}[\.]\d{1,3}$/.test(s);  /* CHANGED */
    }, format: function (s) {
        var a = s.split("."),
            r = "",
            l = a.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var item = a[i];
            if (item.length == 1) {                 /* NEW */
                r += "00" + item;                   /* NEW */
            } else if (item.length == 2) {          /* CHANGED */
                r += "0" + item;
            } else {
                r += item;
            }
        }
        return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(r);
    }, type: "numeric"
});
```

Comment: Out of the box, no IP addresses were sorting correctly for me. It seems like the auto-detection of IP address sorting works and then having this custom parser resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the original tablesorter (v2.0.5) or my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)?

The original has an ipAddress parser included as [one of the default parsers](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js#L916-L934), so as long as the format of the ipAddress is correct, it should work.

The forked version of tablesorter, on the other hand no longer has the ipAddress parser included in the tablesorter core. It was moved into a separate file ([parser-network.js](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-network.js)) and renamed to "ipv4Address" ("ipAddress" still works for backwards compatibility). An image parser took its place.

[Here is a demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-ip-address.html) showing ipv4, ipv6 and MAC address sorting.